# error: interactions numpy pandas matplotlib seaborn statsmodels

Tags: numpy

could anyone help me on explain this error?
I am working on a very easy models (linear an logistical regressions) using statmodels and other libraries. I am using Google Colab. I checked for funnctionality of all code in Monday  Jan 15th, no problem arised. But when running yesterday by noon, this emerged:

`----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
last)
 in <cell line: 14>()
12 pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)
13
---> 14 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
15 import sklearn.metrics as metrics
16 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

```
10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py in <module>
     55 IS_PYSTON = hasattr(sys, "pyston_version_info")
     56 HAS_REFCOUNT = getattr(sys, 'getrefcount', None) is not None and not IS_PYSTON
---> 57 HAS_LAPACK64 = numpy.linalg._umath_linalg._ilp64
     58 
     59 _OLD_PROMOTION = lambda: np._get_promotion_state() == 'legacy'

AttributeError: module 'numpy.linalg._umath_linalg' has no attribute '_ilp64'``
```

---

Finally I found a solution:
Running: !pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy pandas matplotlib seaborn statsmodels
and restarting the runtime.

Could anyone help me undrestand what happened here? Was there a change in any of the packages? Specially, I want to find a way to prevent this malfunctions in the future.
Thank you.

Comment: Why does your title include irrelevant libraries?

Comment: To attract more attention, consider making the title more descriptive. Your question would also benefit from the code required to reproduce the problem.